# How to combine splitted data from one cell in another one in Google SpreadSheets

Tags: split, google-sheets

I have a cell with multiple rows (Alt+Enter), and I want split it and use all split single data in another cell.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please tick the answer as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apply [`join`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) after splitting, with the first argument being the text you want in between types. Concatenate with the text that should be at the beginning and the end.

```
="[[Category: " & join("]]" & char(10) & "[[Category: ", split(A2,char(10))) & "]]"
```

---

For more complex text processing, consider [`regexreplace`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en).

Comment: thanks, it works, after replace "," to ";" before and inside SPLIT. With regular expression I don't know how to do the same)

Comment: The usage of "," to ";" depends on your regional settings. "," is used in US, for example.